# can't read the value of a checkbox array after submit a form

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, form-submit

I don't know what I miss here but I try to make a really simple form with a checbox in it, here is the html:

```
(...)
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="js"> Javascript <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="php">  PHP <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="sql">  SQL <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="html">  HTML <br>
(...)
```

and here is the php snippet which suppose to handle it:

```
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST['test']);
    echo '</pre>';
    print_r($_POST)
    echo '<hr>';
```

here is the output

```
Array
Array
(     
    [stuff1] => 0
    [stuff2] => 5
    [stuff3] => 2
    [test] => Array        
)
```

The other input of the forms are well display but I can't parse the content of the array which is just a sample string named "array"...

If i try to do a

```
var_dump($_POST["test"]); //this is what I get: string 'Array' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, the reason is that I'm using an old framework that make a strange statement within or without magic_quotes activated, Ive got magic_quotes activated so it's escaping any array contained in the $_POST variables...

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($value && !$is_magic_quotes_gpc) {
        $_POST["$key"] = addslashes($value);
    }
}
```

I just remove this snippet and everything went allright

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial about how to handle checkbox using php : http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Basically your `$_POST['test']` is an array, that is empty if no checkbox was checked. And that would be like `["js","php"]` if the user selected `js` and `php`.

If you want to cycle through all selected choices, you could do :

```
foreach ($it in $_POST['test']) {
   echo $it
}
```

Comment: look at my code, I'm doing a print_r($_POST['test']); and I get no value because it's not an array, it s a string! And of course I previously selected some box before submit my form, I really don't know what is happening here...

Comment: It's printing "Array" because the array is empty I think .. what does it do with `var_dump($_POST["test"])`

Comment: string 'Array' (length=5)
I'm confuse :/

Comment: ahaha, I think it should be something in my dev environment, I remove FirePHP and Xdebug and the bug is still there...I duno how to debug this